How do I solve Python-vlc converter error?
I checked at a lot of forums and guides without finding any solution.
I am using python-vlc to read a video thanks to a python code. Here is the code i am using :
video_path = "./../vidéos/videoplayback.mp4"

instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_player_new()

media = instance.media_new(video_path)
player.set_media(media)

player.set_rate(1.0)
player.play()

But at the line player.play() i have the following error popping :
[0000014f26724ca0] d3d11va generic error: FindVideoServiceConversion failed
[0000014f23bbae00] direct3d11 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
[0000014f26766700] dxva2 generic error: FindVideoServiceConversion failed
[0000014f23bbb0a0] direct3d11 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4

Followed by another one that appears like a hundred times in 2 seconds :
[0000014f26766270] chain filter error: Too high level of recursion (3)
[0000014f26765f00] main filter error: Failed to create video converter

The video characteristics i am trying to read (in .mp4 and in French, sorry) :

I am using my computer which is under Windows 11 Family, python v3.11.9 and python-vlc v3.0.20123
To solve the problem, I tried to uninstall and reinstall python-vlc.
I tried to play another .mp4 video and it worked properly. Here are the characteristics:

I don't know if it's useful, but at first, I have this message appearing for this video :
[00000169659dbb90] avcodec decoder: Using D3D11VA (Intel(R) UHD Graphics, vendor 8086(Intel), device 8a56, revision 7) for hardware decoding
As recommended in several forum, i tried to change vlc video output parameter which change nothing at all.
I tried to put print between each lines and this is at the player.play() that the problem appears.
My windows is up to date. Same for my GPU driver.
I found this post : python-vlc tkinter application for playing videos on linux
He is asking almost the same question but got no answer to it.
If you need any other information, I will provide it as soon as possible !
